# Creating subfolders inside a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

With this code, I can create folder.

```
         function createNewFolder() {
            var name =   "newfolder"

            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {

            var request = gapi.client.request({
               'path': '/drive/v2/files/',
               'method': 'POST',
               'headers': {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',

               },
               'body':{
                   "title" : name,
                   "mimeType" : "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                   "parents": [{
                        "kind": "drive#file",
                        "id": FOLDER_ID
                    }]
               }
            });

            request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
           });
        }

    }
 }
```

But when this is created, I want to create 5 subfolders with different names (apple, pear, banana, kiwi and orange) in it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the beginning of your code into:

```
function createNewFolder(folderName) {
    var name = folderName
```

By giving the function a parameter, you can execute it multiple times with different names, so you can loop through an array (as example) and create them:

```
var names = ['apple', 'pear', 'something']

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    createNewFolder(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: The var name is actually the id (folder gets the name id)

Comment: And the folders apple and pear must go in the map wit the name id

Comment: var name =   $('[name=id]').val(); This is my var name

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct in using the `parents[]` property to get the `FOLDER_ID`. Then you can use the `FOLDER_ID` to create subfolders within your parent folder. It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder).

> ***The `parents` property can be used when creating a folder as well to create a subfolder.***

[Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266806/5832311):

> ```
> function createSubFolder() {
> var body = new Object();
> body.title = 'SubFolder';
> body.parents = [{'id':'0B5xvxYkWPFpCUjJtZVZiMWNBQlE'}];
> body.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
>
> console.log(body)
> var request = gapi.client.request({
> 'path': '/drive/v2/files',
> 'method': 'POST',
> 'body': JSON.stringify(body)
> });
>
> request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
> }
> ```

Also according to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253909/google-drive-api-create-sub-folders), when creating a sub folder in Google Drive, it must have a parent. So before execute the string `q`, you need to search for the parent root id.

```
string findRootId = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title ='" + RootFolder + "' and trashed = false";
IList<File> _RootId = GoogleDriveHelper.GetFiles(service, findRootId);
         if (_RootId.Count == 0)    
         {      
            _RootId.Add(GoogleDriveHelper.createDirectory(service, RootFolder, "", "root"));
                       Console.WriteLine("Root folder {0} was created.", RootFolder);   
         }      
var id = _RootId[0].Id;
string Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '" + id + "' in parents and title ='" + GoogleDriveFolderName + "' and trashed = false";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But what if the id keeps changing ?? Because now u have body.parents
but my goals is if the link id doesnt exist (for example user 120 ) it makes folder with name 120. this is reapeted with each non existing user

Comment: What u meen with the code string findrootid ( i use javascript)