# google-drive api: creation of subfolder under root instead of the parent folder ID provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. The code below shows I am requesting to create a subfolder under a specific parent ID... yet the folder gets created in the root of the drive instead. Any help immensely appreciated!

```
def _makeFolder(service, folderName, parentId):
_fileMetadata = {
    'name'      : folderName,
    'mimeType'  : CONST_MIME_FOLDER,
    'parents'   : parentId
}
_newFolderId = service.files().create(body=_fileMetadata, fields='id').execute()
return(_newFolderId.get('id'))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253909/google-drive-api-create-sub-folders

Comment: Not a duplicate; my call uses the parents field and has the right parent folder ID... Still stuck - any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add list to the parents field:

```
'parents'   : [parentId]
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put it as a list object!